# Codeigniter Hook for common variables but how to override them when needed

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I am trying to use a `pre_controller` hook in Codeigniter to define commonly used variables throughout the stuff I am building. However I am trying to figure out if a controller is my best choice or should I use something else.

What I need is something that can access the DB, Sessions, Etc yet pass this information down to a view. I also need to in various controllers override a common default from these common variables.

Ideas?

Overall I am thinking controller level so I can play with `$this->data[]` entries. But I don't think it being a precontroller I can override that in another controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables into $this->config object

Comment: I do, but some things need be processed by some things in models.. IE: I have a list of css/js files I wanted rolled out into my templates. Which keep an array of those common ones in the config, but I dont keep them with the HTML I keep just the file names, which when processed for the view they get put into the respective tags. However on some views I need an additional script or style so I need to append to the variable making it down which would be find if I could figure out the proper method to use in a hook to pass that down and all around

Comment: Here you can see a multiple view controller i finished for one of my latest works, i hope you find it usefull to get some ideas.
https://github.com/abducted/Multiple-view-loader/blob/master/MultipleViewController.php